# Smart Map plugin - Get visitor's lat/lng

Tags: plugin-smartmap

I'm using the Smart Map plugin but want to render my own maps. All I need is the lat/lng of a visitor yet I can't find it in the documentation. I don't want Smart Maps to render the map for me, I just want the lat/lng.

I'm currently using the Geo plugin to do this but it seems a bit silly having both installed.

Answer (score 3):

Smart Map can indeed do this! <s>It's currently an undocumented feature</s>, because I wasn't sure if/how it was going to evolve over time. However, that feature has changed very little over the past two years, so perhaps it's time to finally document it. :)

**UPDATE:** As of Smart Map 2.3, this is now a [publicly documented feature](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/smart-map/visitor-geolocation/).

Comment: Lindsey sent me an advance copy so I'm sorted. Not quite an answer yet, so I'll leave it open until after the release.

Comment: Updated this answer with a link to the official documentation.